# How to pass a callable object as runnable object? Can we type cast Callable to Runnable?

Tags: java, oop, type-conversion, runnable, callable

How is the below structure possibly working?
Please explain.

Thanks in advance.

```
public abstract class AbstractCallableClass {
    protected abstract V getCallable();

    public void passRunnable() {
        runnableParamterised(this.getCallable());
    }
    
    public void runnableParamterised(Runnable runnable) {
        System.out.println(runnable.toString());
    }
}

class OneCallableClass implements Callable {
    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        return "Any dummy response";
    }
}

class TestClass extends AbstractCallableClass {
    @Override
    protected V getCallable() {
        return new OneCallableClass();
    }
}
```

It's not working as it is mentioned in the above sample. But apparently, the Callable is getting typecast-ed as Runnable when passed as an argument and is working in production.

Comment: What is `V`? Where does it come from?

Comment: Can we get an example that compiles? Excluding `passRunnable`, everything else should be compilable. And no, you can't cast `Callable` to `Runnable`. You can use an adapter though to pass callable wrapped as a runnable.

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** cast `Callable` to a `Runnable` - it will lead to `ClassCastException`, unless the callable is also a runnable (imagine a class implementing both interfaces).

You can implement a simple adapter to wrap a callable and pass it as a runnable, where one is required:

```
public class RunnableAdapter implements Runnable {

  private final Callable<?> callable;

  public RunnableAdapter(Callable<?> callable) {
    this.callable = callable;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      callable.call();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
      throw new RuntimeException(exc);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
runnableParamterised(new RunnableAdapter(callable));
```

Answer (score 0):

> You **can't** cast `Callable` to a `Runnable` - it will lead to `ClassCastException`, unless the callable is also a runnable (imagine a class implementing both interfaces).

+1

Implementing both interfaces (a two-way Adapter) is also pretty straightforward.
The obvious consequences of invoking a `Callable` as a `Runnable` are that you lose its return value and wrap its Exceptions.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CallableRunnable<R> extends Callable<R>, Runnable {
    static <R> CallableRunnable<R> fromCallable(Callable<R> callable) {
        return callable::call;
    }

    static CallableRunnable<Void> fromRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
        return () -> { runnable.run(); return null; };
    }

    @Override
    default void run() {
        try {
            call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

// Tests ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Callable<String> callable = () -> "Hello Callable!";
        Runnable runnable = () -> System.out.println("Hello Runnable!");

        Callable<Void> adaptedRunnable = CallableRunnable.fromRunnable(runnable);
        Runnable adaptedCallable = CallableRunnable.fromCallable(callable);

        System.out.println(adaptedRunnable.call());  // null
        adaptedCallable.run();

        Callable<String> thrower = () -> { throw new Exception("Goodbye Callable."); };
        Runnable adaptedThrower = CallableRunnable.fromCallable(thrower);
        try {
            adaptedThrower.run();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getCause().getMessage());
        }

        String msg = "Hello CallableRunnable!";
        CallableRunnable<String> callableRunnable = () -> { System.out.println(msg); return msg; };
        System.out.println(testMethodRequiresCallable(callableRunnable));
        testMethodRequiresRunnable(callableRunnable);
    }

    static <R> R testMethodRequiresCallable(Callable<R> callable) throws Exception {
        return callable.call();
    }

    static void testMethodRequiresRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
        runnable.run();
    }
}
```